# Allow facebook user to vote once only

Tags: php, database, facebook, vote

The site is a voting site for music artists. Each artist is saved in a database and they have a vote column. Each time a user clicks vote it adds one to the vote column in the database.

I want the users to log in with facebook and vote only ONCE for only ONE artist.

How would i go by doing such thing?

EDIT

This is a screen shot of the database I have.
[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPzrj.png)

Comment: Unclear what you're asking: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where exactly you got stuck, and your question is way too broad for Stackoverflow, but here's how it works:

- Authorize users with your Facebook App.
- Whenever a user votes, store his ID with the vote and check if he already voted for that artist. A voting table could have the following 3 columns: artistId, vote, userId - or if the voting is not a number but just a flag, you could omit the "vote" column.

Links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Thanks, sorry im new to Stackoverflow, but would storing the vote mean that I will need multiple columns for my database for each artist?

Comment: well, you need a table with artistId, vote, userId (from facebook), for example

Comment: Have a look at the edit above, a screenshot of the database I hold. If i ad the userid column how will this store more than one users id's?

Comment: you really need to add those things whenever you create a question on stackoverflow, be as detailed as possible and only ask very specific questions. anyway, you must create a separate table for the votings (with the columns i mentioned), right now you can only store a number and increase it. it is called "normalization". you MUST learn about normalization if you want to use mysql.